# Why isn't a dotnet5.1 package compatible with a traditional .NET PCL?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, asp.net5

I'm trying to use a package that targets `dotnet5.1` from my Portable Class Library, which targets the following platforms (Profile 259):

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8.0
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/9e0b539c9ee3dd105ff55e81c1c32cd2976b71ef/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md) document which explains the motivation/benefit of using the `dotnet5.x` monikers, it says that .NET generations should be interoperable with existing PCLs. It also [lists](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/9e0b539c9ee3dd105ff55e81c1c32cd2976b71ef/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md#portable-profiles) out which generation each PCL profile should be compaitble with, one of them being Profile 259 PCLs which are mapped to the `dotnet5.1` moniker.

So why is it then, that when I try to install a `dotnet5.1` library into my clean Profile 259 PCL, I get this error in Visual Studio:

```
PM> Install-Package Enumerator
...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Enumerator 1.13.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Can someone with experience in .NET Core explain to me why this is happening? Is this a bug in NuGet? If `dotnet5.x` packages can't be used with existing PCLs, then what purpose do they actually serve?

Thanks for helping.

**edit:** It should be noted that the `dotnet5.x` monikers are essentially equivalent to the newer `netstandard1.y` ones (where `y == x - 1`). For more info, see the latest revision of the docs [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md).

Comment: Have you used the latest NuGet package manager?

Comment: @LexLi I suppose so; I'm using whichever one comes with VS 2015 Update 2.

Comment: that's not the latest.

Comment: @LexLi How can that be? Update 2 was just released a few days ago, and support for .NET generations has been around for a long time in NuGet (e.g. with `dnu restore`).

Comment: How long have you been using Visual Studio? NuGet is an extension to Visual Studio and can be updated as such (Tools > Extensions and Updates)

Comment: @JamesKo unfortunately the VS team seems to think NuGet should be updated on its own and as another comment indicates you have to update it separately. Not intuitive but we get used to that.

Comment: This is a bit of a mess right now but watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfxuJsZIK4A&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=1somewhere there they mention about imports. Notes for this meeting is also available: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/04/06/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-april-5-2016/#comment-84725

Comment: @JamesKo any updates on this. I am curious.

Comment: @Thomas .NET Core RC2 has been released, so you should be using the new `netstandard` moniker instead (in this case, `dotnet5.1` maps to `netstandard1.0`).

Comment: @JamesKo That I know ;) ... i just wonder about the PCL compatability question (PCL vs. dotnet/netstandard) and whether NuGet resolves that now properly. Have never tried, not part of my problems. I comment for learning ;)